# WebClient download of application data not returning result set into reader

Tags: c#, webforms, webclient

I am having a major issue with this code I am trying to simply download a list of address from craftycllick server which is xml based I am using webclient to do the download but its failing yet when i go to the browser the  data is

```
 public XmlTextReader readXML(string postcode, string response, string accessCode)
 {
        //Create URL
        string url = $"http://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/xml/rapidaddress?postcode={postcode}&response={response}&key={accessCode}";

        try
        {
            //Create WebRequest
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (Stream responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(textReader);
                        Debug.Assert(reader != null, "Reader is NULL");
                        return reader;
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception("ResponseStream is NULL");
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Xml that is returned is

```
  <CraftyResponse><address_data_formatted><delivery_point><organisation_name>THE BAKERY</organisation_name><department_name/><line_1>1 HIGH STREET</line_1><line_2>CRAFTY VALLEY</line_2><udprn>12345678</udprn></delivery_point><delivery_point><organisation_name>FILMS R US</organisation_name><department_name/><line_1>3 HIGH STREET</line_1><line_2>CRAFTY VALLEY</line_2><udprn>12345679</udprn></delivery_point><delivery_point><organisation_name>FAMILY BUTCHER</organisation_name><department_name/><line_1>7 HIGH STREET</line_1><line_2>CRAFTY VALLEY</line_2><udprn>12345680</udprn></delivery_point><delivery_point><organisation_name/><department_name/><line_1>BIG HOUSE, HIGH STREET</line_1><line_2>CRAFTY VALLEY</line_2><udprn>12345681</udprn></delivery_point><delivery_point><organisation_name/><department_name/><line_1>LITTLE COTTAGE</line_1><line_2>17 HIGH STREET, CRAFTY VALLEY</line_2><udprn>12345682</udprn></delivery_point><delivery_point_count>5</delivery_point_count><town>BIG CITY</town><postal_county>POSTAL COUNTY</postal_county><traditional_county>TRADITIONAL COUNTY</traditional_county><postcode>AA1 1AA</postcode></address_data_formatted></CraftyResponse>
```

And the routine I use to Parse.

```
public DataTable returnAddressList(string postcode, string accessCode)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
            dtReturn.Columns.Add("PropertyItem", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dtReturn.Columns.Add("PropertyValue", Type.GetType("System.String"));

            postcode = postcode.Replace(" ", "");
            XmlTextReader reader = readXML(postcode, "data_formatted", accessCode);

            string option1 = "";
            string option2 = "";

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                if (reader.Name.Equals("line_1"))
                {
                    option1 = reader.ReadString();
                }
                if (reader.Name.Equals("udprn"))
                {
                    option2 = reader.ReadString();
                }
                if (option1 != "" && option2 != "")
                {
                    dtReturn.Rows.Add(new object[] { option1, option2 });
                    option1 = "";
                    option2 = "";
                }
            }

            return dtReturn;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And My Calling code to the above function is

```
  fhsBl.Helpers.CraftyPostCodeLookup _postCodeLookup = new fhsBl.Helpers.CraftyPostCodeLookup();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

       dt = _postCodeLookup.returnAddressList("AA11AA", "API KEY DONT BE NOSY");
```

**Edit 1**
 Ok has advised i changed my code to use the using statment and read the contents within that but I am getting another error and still no producing of data.

```
 public DataTable readXML(string postcode, string response, string accessCode)
    {
        //Create URL
        string url = $"http://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/xml/rapidaddress?postcode={postcode}&response={response}&key={accessCode}";

        try
        {
            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
            dtReturn.Columns.Add("PropertyItem", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dtReturn.Columns.Add("PropertyValue", Type.GetType("System.String"));

            //Create WebRequest
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (Stream responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(textReader);
                        postcode = postcode.Replace(" ", "");

                        string option1 = "";
                        string option2 = "";

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            if (reader.Name.Equals("line_1"))
                            {
                                option1 = reader.ReadString();
                            }
                            if (reader.Name.Equals("udprn"))
                            {
                                option2 = reader.ReadString();
                            }
                            if (option1 != "" && option2 != "")
                            {
                                dtReturn.Rows.Add(new object[] { option1, option2 });
                                option1 = "";
                                option2 = "";
                            }
                        }
                        return dtReturn;
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception("ResponseStream is NULL");
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Screen shot of debugging

[image]

Comment: What's failing? Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: @pijemcolu i actually look at the stack trace and its saying cannot read from a closed text stream if that make since that is within the catch try element of returnAddressList

Comment: In that case you have propably found the error ... You shouldn't `return Reader` inside a using block. You could try changing the method to return a string and then you can parse the string.

Comment: @pijemcolu can you explain in a code answer then i can mark you as the answer

Comment: @pijemcolu  its not string its a xml formated document that I am trying to parse. Hence why i am trying to use XmlTextReader

Comment: Msdn states that: When a reader is first created and initialized, there is no information available. You must call Read to read the first node.

This method requires at least four bytes from the data stream in order to begin parsing. If fewer than four bytes are returned and there is no more data in the stream, the method will fail. If there is more data in the stream, the method will block parsing until receipt of the fourth byte. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @pijemcolu please provide a complete answer  and i can give you the kudos u deserve. instead of just comment works out better for u.

Comment: @pijemcolu please see my edits please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the discussion in comments went ...

```
using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(textReader);
                    Debug.Assert(reader != null, "Reader is NULL");
                    return reader;
                }
```

You create a TextReader object which you are later using in the constructor fo XmlTextReader reader ... after you return XmlTextReader and when you exit the using block you dispose of and close the textReader, hence the error that you can not read from a closed textReader. The issue lies in architecture imo.

You should try pulling the the while loop logic from the Parse method you have into the the using block such as ....

```
using(TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(textReader);

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.Name.Equals("line_1"))
                {
                    option1 = reader.ReadString();
                }
                if(reader.Name.Equals("udprn"))
                {
                    option2 = reader.ReadString();
                }
                if(option1 != "" && option2 != "")
                {
                    dtReturn.Rows.Add(new object[] { option1, option2 });
                    option1 = "";
                    option2 = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. You can not return from `using statment` when You want return stream because when You exit from `using`, You call `Dispose` method and close the stream.

First You must change `readXML` method.

```
public DataTable readXML(string postcode, string response, string accessCode)
 {
        //Create URL
        string url = $"http://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/xml/rapidaddress?postcode={postcode}&response={response}&key={accessCode}";

        DataTable dataTableResult  = null;

        try
            //Create WebRequest
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (Stream responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(textReader);
                        Debug.Assert(reader != null, "Reader is NULL");

                        dataTableResult = returnAddressList(postcode, response, reader)
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception("ResponseStream is NULL");
            }

           return dataTableResult;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

And next You must change definition of `returnAddressList` method to use stream from parameter like this:

```
   public DataTable returnAddressList(string postcode, string accessCode, XmlTextReader reader)
```

and deleted line where You call `readXML` method

```
  XmlTextReader reader = readXML(postcode, "data_formatted", accessCode); - delete this line
```

It is not very good refactoring, but You can see what to do and where is the problem.

Comment: OK, but Your screeanshot in not realy helpful Give Us something better like lins whre problem is appear nad text of error